# Setup JUnit test timeout using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, junit, timeout

I have found so far 2 ways to setup JUnit test timeout. Either using:

```
@Test(timeout=XXX)
```

Or using something like:

```
@ClassRule
public static Timeout timeoutRule = new Timeout(XXX, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

In my case, I have a Test Runner as a main class to run all my test suites, so I can execute the tests as an executable jar.
I'd like this runner to setup the timeouts dinamically using reflection.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the timeout feature to a custom test runner like so:

```
public class TimeoutTestRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public TimeoutTestRunner(Class<?> clazz) throws InitializationError {
        super(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected Statement withPotentialTimeout(FrameworkMethod method, Object test, Statement next) {
        return FailOnTimeout.builder()
                // you'll probably want to configure/inject this value rather than hardcode it ...
                .withTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build(next);
    }
}
```

Using this test runner the tests in the following test case ...

```
@RunWith(TimeoutTestRunner.class)
public class YourTest {

    @Test
    public void willTimeout() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(50);
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void willNotTimeout() throws InterruptedException {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

... will behave as follows:

- `willTimeout`: will fail with a `TestTimedOutException`
- `willNotTimeout`: will pass

Although you will need your tests to be run via this runner you will be able to control their timeout setting from one place and provide custom timeout derivation strategies such as `if test name matches <some regex> then timeout is x else ...`.

Comment: Can't extend BlockJUnit4ClassRunner, because my runner is already extending another class.
Is there any other way to do that without having to extend this?
Maybe insert a new timeout field into the class, or inserting the timeout value to the test annotation at runtime...

Comment: @AlexanderRumanovsk: I really don't think you'll be able to change the test classes on the fly. I think a custom runner is the right fit for your use case.  You wrote: "my runner is already extending another class" so it must (somewhere up the hierarchy) be extending `org.junit.runner.Runner` so if all else fails (i.e. if the runner you are using does not have an easy hook for applying this timeout) you can always override the `run()` method and wrap the call to `super.run()` in a timeout block.which has a `run()` method.